# Differences in inheritance of parent objects prototype

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I found 3 ways to inherit the prototype of another Object-constructor:

Can I use all three? => They seem to work if I test the draw() method on a Rectangle instance...

Are there other ways of doing this?

```
function Shape(shapeName){
    this.shapeName = shapeName;
}
Shape.prototype.draw = function(){
    console.log('I am a '+this.shapeName+' and I am drawing myself');
}

function Rectangle(shapeName,l,b){
    Shape.apply(this,arguments);
    this.lengte = l;
    this.breadth = b;
}

// Possibility 1 ==> Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
// Possibility 2 ==> Object.assign(Rectangle.prototype,Shape.prototype);
// Possibility 3 ==> Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;
```

Comment: I don't think they're entirely equivalent. When you create an instance of `Rectangle`, do they all return true for `rectangle instanceof Shape` ? Also, you're missing the `extends` keyword ;)

Comment: What about ES6 classes?

Comment: Only the first one does actual *inheritance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use all three?

Sort of, but I would strongly recommend using Possibility 1 (plus setting `constructor` on the result to `Rectangle`):

```
function Shape(shapeName){
    this.shapeName = shapeName;
}
Shape.prototype.draw = function(){
    console.log('I am a '+this.shapeName+' and I am drawing myself');
}

function Rectangle(shapeName,l,b){
    Shape.apply(this,arguments);
    this.lengte = l;
    this.breadth = b;
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

Why I wouldn't use Possibility 2: It copies everything over, which means subsequent modifications to `Shape.prototype` won't be inherited by  `Rectangle.prototype`.

Why I wouldn't use Possibility 3: It means you can't give `Rectangle` methods that `Shape` doesn't have (since adding to `Rectangle.prototype` is adding to `Shape.prototype` as they're the same object), and it falsely makes `triangle instanceof Rectangle` true if you also have `Triangle` created the same way and used `triangle = new Triangle()` to create `triangle`.

---

Possibility 1 is also essentially what ES2015+ `class` syntax does when you do `class Rectangle extends Shape { }`. And in fact, what I would recommend using (potentially with a transpiler):

```
class Shape {
    constructor(shapeName) {
        this.shapeName = shapeName;
    }
    draw() {
        console.log('I am a '+this.shapeName+' and I am drawing myself');
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    constructor(shapeName, l, b){
        super(shapeName);
        this.lengte = l; // <=== Maybe you meant "length"?
        this.breadth = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: That's true of "Possibility 3" rather than 2, but I think the point is sufficiently made that having both `prototype` properties referring to the same object is not useful. :-)